# Configuring barrier option in Quantlib-Python

Tags: option-pricing, quantlib

Is there a possibility to configure the period the barrier is active, using Quantlib for python? Namely to set up the start and the end dates we compare the spot vs the barrier.

If we look at quantlib-python-docs (https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instruments/options.html?highlight=BarrierOption#ql.BarrierOption), the ql.BarrierOption class constructor seems not to have such a possibility. Should we use another class?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the `ql.PartialTimeBarrierOption` class which prices windowed barriers.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your own payoff classes for the different types of Barrier Options. Then when you calculate the payoff you can specify which data to run or when to start the barrier payoff. Working on a similar homework now